Binding Exception while using @TestPropertySource in Spring
I'm trying to load the application-test.yaml file for my tests
This is my code,
@Provider("provider")
@PactBroker
//@ActiveProfiles({"test"})
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.yaml")
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT) 

When I use the @TestPropertySource annotation, I get an exception.
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:  Could not bind properties to 'Myclass' : prefix=spring.security.verification, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'spring.security.verification' to com.test.Myclass

However, if I use @ActiveProfiles({"test"}) instead, everything works as expected.
I'm wondering why there's a difference in behavior. I would assume both annotations would achieve the same result.

@TestPropertySource, like @PropertySource doesn't understand YAML only properties files. YOu shouldn't do that to load a test specificy file use @ActiveProfiles instead and let Spring Boot do the heavy lifting (which will load the yaml file).

Try with @TestPropertySource("classpath:/application-test.yaml")
